# insert new instance using API of GCE

Tags: java, api, google-compute-engine

i write a code to create instance in GCE using java API 
but this code does not work i get the following error

```
403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
```

my code is posted bellow does it has any error or does it need any library to import please help me 
the library that i import are

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.compute.Compute;
import com.google.api.services.compute.ComputeScopes;
import com.google.api.services.compute.model.Instance;
import com.google.api.services.compute.model.InstanceList;
import com.google.api.services.compute.model.NetworkInterface;
import com.google.api.services.compute.model.Operation;
import com.google.api.services.compute.model.Zone;
import com.google.api.services.compute.model.ZoneList;



  private static void createInstance(String projectId, JsonFactory jsonFactory,Compute compute) throws IOException {
        Instance instance = new Instance();
        instance.setFactory(jsonFactory);

        // Select a machine type.
        String machine = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/hindproj/global/machineTypes/n1-standard-1";
        instance.setMachineType(machine);

        // Get a name from the user.
        String name = "v1";
        instance.setName(name);
        // Use the default network.  Could select here if needed.
        List<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = new ArrayList<NetworkInterface>();
        NetworkInterface iface = new NetworkInterface();
        iface.setFactory(jsonFactory);
        iface.setName("eth0");
        iface.setNetwork("https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/hindproj/global/networks/default");//( COMPUTE_API + "/projects/" + projectId + "/networks/default");
        networkInterfaces.add(iface);
        instance.setNetworkInterfaces(networkInterfaces);

        // Select a zone.
        String zone = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/hindproj/zones/us-central1-b";
        instance.setZone(zone);
        Compute.Instances.Insert ins = compute.instances().insert(projectId,zoneName, instance);

        // Finally, let's run it.
        Operation op = ins.execute();
        System.out.println(op.toPrettyString());
        System.out.println(instance.toPrettyString());
      }
```

Comment: Is it missing a boot disk?

Comment: Are you using the correct ComputeScopes (ComputeScopes.COMPUTE and not ComputeScopes.COMPUTE_READONLY)? We cannot see the code creating the _compute_ instance, but setting the read-only scope can give the same error you have.

Answer (score 0):

Machine type resources are zonal, not global.  Try https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/hindproj/zones/us-central1-b/machineTypes/n1-standard-1